# Tomcat 8 - Only localhost(127.0.0.1) running index.jsp

Tags: java, html, jsp, localhost, tomcat8

I'm new to tomcat and servlets. So I'm trying to test a simple `jsp` page on my tomcat 8 container. When I open the `index.jsp` file from `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` it works fine i.e. `index.jsp` page displays `html` as well as outputs the `jsp` code results. But when I run it through the pc's *ip address*(which is 192.168.1.100 on the local network), the browser displays the `html` but the `jsp` code is totally ignored. Here's a part of `index.jsp` :

```
</head><body>
<% 
    out.print("<h2>Hello, I'm running!!</h2>");
%>
<header><h1>The Real Thing</h1><h4>Vote or die!</h4></header>
<main>
```

I've even changed the tomcat web.xml's `welcome-list`, putting `index.jsp` before `index.html` but it's not working. So, if localhost is running the `jsp` code from `index.jsp` then why does the local network ip address not running the `jsp` code?

Any help would be appreciated.

> NOTE : I deleted the index.jsp from `/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT/` but `192.168.1.100` is still displaying the web page while `localhost` is giving 404 page not found.

Comment: Could you please provide your tomcat configuration file?

Comment: I'm not sure. Do you mean TOMCAT_HOME/web.xml ? @oschlueter

Comment: I believe it to be the conf/server.xml

Comment: The link in your comment doesn't work. Feel free to add the content of the xml file to your question.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_a-6I0pHmtBSjlaQzk5Z2pvQjg

Answer (score 0):

You need to make two changes to your server.xml

1. Add a new `Host` element with the `name` attribute pointing to the DNS name of your computer/server. If server has no name registered with DNS, you may use the local name resolver (in unices it's the `/etc/hosts` file, there is a similar file in Windows) to add a host name of your choice and map it to an ip assigned to the server's network interface.
2. You then need to change the `defaultHost` attribute, on the `Engine` element named `catalina`,  to point to this host you just added